# When subclassing NSObject, what difference does it make to import "Foundation.h" or "NSObject.h"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsobject, foundation

Here we see the same subclass of `NSObject` each using a different `#import` statement. What difference, if any, does this make for my subclass? What difference, if any, does this make for my final compiled program?

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
    @interface Card : NSObject
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface Card : NSObject
```

Comment: what is problem in question to make it down vote?

Comment: i did not downvote, but probably poor english. i see no other problem with the question. -- attempted to clean it up to avoid further downvoting.. GL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
    @interface Card : NSObject
```

In this code ,you are only importing the `NSObject` class of `Foundation` framework,So you can't inherit the other classes of `Foundation` framework.

While

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  @interface Card : NSObject
```

This code allow you to inherit any of the class provided by the Framework like `NSProxy`,`NSRange` etc.,as you are importing whole framework.

Hope it Helps....:)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is very simple.

When you use:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
```

It'll import only the NSObject header file of Foundation framework.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

All framework have a master header file, which includes all public headers of that particular framework. In common this master header file naming convention is like FrameworkName.h , hence for Foundation framework it'll be `Foundation.h` and it imports all other public header files of Foundation framework. So if you include that, you don't need to import any other class headers from that framework.